# CakePHP select a file from server

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm building an app based on CakePHP framework and [Croogo CMS](http://croogo.org). Basically there will be a simple intranet section where after logging in the users will be able to view and download some files.

Within administration I'm planning a simple section where the administrator will select files from ones previously uploaded into CMS and laying in `/app/webroot/files` folder. Here I would like to implement a simple **file picker** to let administrator easily select files that will be added to that intranet.

I was googling for a while but found nothing useful - merely pages about file upload.

**My question**: is there any plugin or something similar to my needs that I could use or do I have to write it down myself?

If there is nothing useable I was planning to do it this way:

- administrator will have to upload intranet dedicated files directly to a folder `/app/webroot/files/intranet/`
- within intranet documents administration section I will then list all present files, fill them into `<ul>` list as links and using `jQuery` fill some hidden form fields in background from which I would then gather information about files that are being added into the intranet

Is this a good approach or do You have better and simpler solution?

Many thanks for Your responses in advance!

Comment: Files in `webroot` are public and directly accessible, if you want to restrict access you'll have to move them to some other place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lector said, webroot files are public, so you will need to save them to somewhere outside webroot, perhaps in another folder inside app. You can use the [Media view](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html) to allow download of those restricted files. You could display all the files in a certain folder using PHP similar to how it is done [here](http://www.clanthemes.com/tutorials-view-140-display-all-files-in-a-directory.html).

Comment: I was not asking about the frontend and the file download though the MediaView would help - +1 for that. But totaly not an answer to my question(s)...

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood. So the files are already uploaded and you just need them added to a sort of list? In that case, you have a habtm association allow access to certain files for certain users. I could go into more details, but I want to make sure that is correct.

Comment: Nope, my question is about administration - if there is some plugin to list the files within a certain directory (that might not be within webroot) or if my suggestion about writing it down myself is correct (supposing the target directory will be outside webroot).

Comment: The second link shows you how to list all the files in a directory.

Comment: OK, thank U, I did it using MediaView while the source folder is within the /app/ folder...